# Async Yield call returning undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, redux-saga

I have an async function for getting token from firebase. But when I fired this function returned undefined.
When I consol.log my async function it's return token. After Yield call, returns undefined.
I am a new student and I have no idea what is happening. So..If anyone can help me with this problem It's really helped me with my studies. Thank you.❤️

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(AddUserTokenListener())
    }, [])

async function getUserIDAsync() {
        const idTokenResult = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult();
        // console.log('User JWT: ', idTokenResult); But this will return token
    }
    
    export function* getUserToken() {
        try {
            const userToken = yield call(getUserIDAsync);
           // console.log(userToken) this will return undefined .
            if (userToken) {
                console.log(userToken)
                yield put(AddUserTokenSuccess(userToken))
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            yield put(AddUserTokenField(error))
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `call` ?

Comment: do you await async result ?

Comment: `what is call` @Barney apparently this is a redux-saga question.

Comment: @zenixo: you're getting undefined because `getUserIDAsync` has no return statement. The fix is to add `return idTokenResult`.

Comment: Good catch @NicholasTower. Do you want to post that as answer, or do you consider this a typo-level mistake?

Comment: I'd say more of a typo-level mistake.

Comment: @Nicholas Tower Its works.Thank you..❤️